# Android bluetooth - Accept a call, reject a call, and display caller ID

Tags: android, bluetooth, voip

I'm integration bluetooth support in my Android app for VOIP calling scenarios. Goal: display caller ID on bluetooth device, allow accept/reject of incoming/active calls through the BT peripheral. Without any work, everything works as expected when calling with the native dialer on Android but I can't find the appropriate APIs to implement the same behavior in our app - are these not exposed?

If a VOIP call is initiated through our app, we start the bluetooth SCO connection and listen for any media /state changes. Pressing the 'answer/reject' button results in a DISCONNECTED state change event (could use this to reject the call but that's not reliable as the same event is received if the BT device is disconnected). I haven't found any leads on displaying the appropriate caller ID (a custom string that I want to provide) or answering calls. Anyone been on this path and have some pointers?

Thanks!